# Verification of power series solution to differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that $$y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$$ is the solution of the differential equation $(x+1)y+y’=0$. So we differentiate $y$ to get $$y’=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}x^{n-1}$$ and substitute into the differential equation but I can’t seem to get zero. Please help.

Comment: Something wrong with the question. This series does not give you  a solution to the DE.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: The series is for $y(x)=\ln(1+x)$. This has a differential equation $(1+x)y'(x)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we rewrite the differential equation:
$$
y' = - y (x+1) \implies \frac{y'}{y} = - (x+1) \implies \left(\ln {y}\right)' = -(x+1)
$$

Hence integrating we obtain
$$
y(x) = k \operatorname e ^{-\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}} 
$$
but as pointed out by @Lutz Lehmann , the series is the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$:
$$
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n = 1 }^ {\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n
$$

They are different.